# Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I Created a Sample WCF service and was trying to host in Windows Service, I installed the service using InstallUtility.exe but When I tried to start the service it give the error "Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller
" in EventLog and also it pop up the services stop automatically if they have no use.

Any Idea how can I proceed further and can access WCF services..

Best Regards

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216606/why-cant-i-install-my-service/4217077#4217077

Answer (score 5):

Your service threw an error before it was able to open you servicehost first step I would take is add a catch and a trace write for any caught errors.  If that doesn't do the trick you need to use [system.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) to see whats up.